# 2 outs with bases loaded, runner misses second

Tags: rules, baseball

This happened the other day in a game I was watching.

There were 2 outs with the bases loaded. The batter hit ball over the left fielder's head.  He reached the 3rd base, and 3 runs scored.  The defensive team appealed that the batter missed the second base, umpire later called the batter out.

How many runs should count?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a force play, so the batter is out either when he is tagged out or when the ball reaches the base.

If there were runners behind that would otherwise score, then per [5.09(d)](https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-images/image/upload/mlb/atcjzj9j7wrgvsm8wnjq.pdf), they could not score if the runner ahead made the third out on appeal.  But in your scenario, there are no runners behind the play.

So all 3 preceding runners score.  The third out happened after they reached home.  If the defense noticed the miss immediately and threw to second rather than to try to tag someone at home, then it would depend on the timing of when the base is tagged and when the runners reach home.  Only the runners reaching the plate prior to the third out can score.

Comment: The runner missing second base does not institute a force play, so the out cannot be recorded simply by tagging second base after the runner has run by. The defense must either tag the runner, or call time after the runner scores to execute an appeal play.